# How to remove other values in a object key array if particular value exist?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am working on an angular project and I have an object like this

```
const obj = {
  fruits: ['apple', 'orange', 'None'],
  nation: ['usa'],
  city: ['New York', 'Delhi', 'None'],
  name: ['one', 'two'],
}
```

if the object key values have a 'None' value I have to remove the other values and keep it 'None' value only.

The answer looks like below:

```
const obj = {
  fruits: ['None'],
  nation: ['usa'],
  city: ['None'],
  name: ['one', 'two'],
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Loop through object, if value includes `None`, replace the value to the key with `['None']`.

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  if (v.includes('None')) obj[k] = ['None']
})
```

```js
const obj = {
  fruits: ['apple', 'orange', 'None'],
  nation: ['usa'],
  city: ['New York', 'Delhi', 'None'],
  name: ['one', 'two'],
}
  
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  if (v.includes('None')) obj[k] = ['None']
})

console.log(obj)
```

For [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGAzATgK4CWUEAXDANoDkAhgA4MA2ApjQDQw0j51gBzdlxoA5cOwC6HbDDB0oxcJVqEIdGtNnBSATxVjWAdxgBNXgGtO3ACKtmAC2LWxEzTJzyAtqwNuRUEYg7pgAvpiYULoMrDAA0qy6qDAWiSC4MFEx6XBIANyymADySKzAUAB0rGBQ+MSsEAAUCIgAlBW4vACidMAOjY1UFlwAbpKtqAB8GLLEGY0jFcRgwMyEACYNja5g7K0TLUMwdBDxiZLJtOK7mmGtEaCQIGwVzCACzUitQA).

Comment: angular6 typescript throwing error 'error TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type '{}'

Comment: Does your `obj` value always has array type ?

Comment: Yes. I have to send the payload above format only. obj value always has array type

Comment: The error indicates the value could be `{}`. It works at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGAzATgK4CWUEAXDANoDkAhgA4MA2ApjQDQw0j51gBzdlxoA5cOwC6HbDDB0oxcJVqEIdGtNnBSATxVjWAdxgBNXgGtO3ACKtmAC2LWxEzTJzyAtqwNuRUEYg7pgAvpiYULoMrDAA0qy6qDAWiSC4MFEx6XBIANyymADySKzAUAB0rGBQ+MSsEAAUCIgAlBW4vACidMAOjY1UFlwAbpKtqAB8GLLEGY0jFcRgwMyEACYNja5g7K0TLUMwdBDxiZLJtOK7mmGtEaCQIGwVzCACzUitQA).